# Fetching user details in React from django-rest-auth gives back 403 (Forbidden) - Using authtoken

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch-api, django-rest-auth

In my project, I have Django Rest Framework managing the backend and React on the frontend.

I am currently implementing the authentication system, so I have just switched the `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings for the `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` from `rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny` to `rest_framework.authtoken` (before everything worked just fine).

Just to make things clearer, here is my `settings.py` (from `INSTALLED_APPS`):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Custom Apps
    'rest_framework',
    'assessments',
    'corsheaders',
    'accounts',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    'allauth.socialaccount'  # needed for delete user
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
        'rest_framework.authtoken'
    ]
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.RegisterProfileSerializer',
}

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.UserProfileSerializer'
}

SITE_ID = 2
```

Also, tho make things as 'restful' as possible, I have used `django-rest-auth` in order to have endpoints form my authentication system.

So far I have managed to implement API endpoints for `rest-auth/registration/` and `rest-auth/users`.
Again, from the API point of view, everything works. In fact, I am able to register a user with an extra field and to see the user details correctly.

My problem is that when I try to make a `GET` request via the `fetch` function in React, I receive back a `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/ 403 (Forbidden)`.

I thought this is due to the tokens, so after a little search I have found out this way to make the fetch request:

```
async getUserRole() {
    await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/user/",
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': ' Token e68edf2d326bef3b12b3008c851261b0c7c3dced',
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ userRole: data.role }))
  }
```

As you can see I am specifying the actual token for the current user, as shown in the admin page:

[image]

*(I know that from this picture you might be thinking I am trying to make the `GET` request when logged in as the admin, and therefore the token is not right, but I am actually logging out and then back in as the user `mirko` from the Django Rest Framework API.)*

So, is there anybody that knows what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is was that I have to add

```
DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
```

To the `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings, as specified [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Answer (score 2):

I used a google chrome "API Tester" to test my api, the issue was that my admin portal was logged in with the same user and it was preventing me from sending a post request. I had the authentication classes session and token.

Answer (score 0):

Logout from Django Admin, or try to login with different user than Django Admin.